# How to open a file with login system?

Tags: java, file-io, authentication

I've made a program a checks whether the username and & password are correct or not, but I want to open a file with a defined path if they are correct. How do I do that? This is what I've tried:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class Login {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int pass;
        String un;
        String file_name = "C:/Users/Username/Desktop";

        System.out.println("Welcome, please enter the username and password");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Username?:");
        un = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Password?:");
        pass = scan.nextInt();
        if (un.equals("Admin") && pass == 123) {
            System.out.println("That's correct");
            Readfile file = new Readfile(file_name);
            String[] aryLines = file.OpenFile();

        } else {
            System.out.println("You ain't the Admin");
        }
    }
}
```

The login checker works, but I can't open the file. It says among other that `Readfile cannot be resolved to a type`

Comment: First hit on google when searching for "java read text file": an [so article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716503/best-way-to-read-a-text-file).

Comment: But that's without the login

Comment: If you want me to do your (home-)work, you need to pay me. A bit of your own programming-effort is required.

Comment: It's not my homework.... I'm just interested in making such a program.

Comment: Is Readfile a class you wrote? Is it in the same package as your Login class? Do you have a JAR file or just class files? Do you get the error at compile time or at runtime? Please provide the commands you use to compile and run your program.

Comment: Have solved the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because ReadFile is not resolved to type as there is no such a class.

You can use BufferedReader along with FileReader to read text file. as below:

```
    BufferedReader br = null;

    try {
        String line; 
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\testing.txt"));
        while ((line= br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I guess Readfile is a custom class and it's a classpath issue. But we need more information to be sure.

Answer (score -1):

```
String file_name = "C:/Users/Username/Desktop";
```

is not a file name, it is a folder name. You need to add something like that:

```
String file_name = "C:/Users/Username/Desktop/filename.txt";
```

Also, after you do that, you should check your code, benefiting from examples on internet. I didn't try but it looks like there are going to be some errors; the last one is my advice to you.

Comment: This might be true but does not answer the OPs question (Readfile cannot be resolved to a type).

Comment: I think it's because of classpath, and this is only a suggestion. If try to do that it maybe help.